# Every single Qt application crashes in one place?

Tags: qt, libiconv

Basically, all of the Qt applications I try to run will crash in one place:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000100f4f570 in QIconvCodec::createIconv_t ()
#2  0x0000000100f5043b in QIconvCodec::convertToUnicode ()
#3  0x0000000100032c7e in QString::fromLocal8Bit ()
#4  0x0000000100e7cb89 in QSystemLocale::fallbackLocale ()
#5  0x00000001000161e0 in QLocalePrivate::updateSystemPrivate ()
```

I suspect it has something to do with `iconv` as it's not very "stable" on Mac OS X. I have no idea what the issue is, and I've tried to reinstall `libiconv` from Macports and even built it myself, and I still get the same issue.

Maybe it dlsyms the needed symbol (which might be missing) and then jumps to the address, causing that (hence the `0x0000000000000000` in the backtrace).

**What could be the possible issue?** (sorry if this is the wrong place to ask it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this same issue and ended up building the debug version of the Qt libraries to figure out what was going on. It appears that the Qt library assumes there is a /usr/lib/libconv.dylib on the machine. For my machine the solution was a simple as...

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib

Comment: Adding my 0.2CAD comment here, for brevity, and a big thank you to @peter for providing the solution. I am running OSX 10.6.8 and I was unable to run VB for ages ... It was always throwing:  

`Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)`
`Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000`
..
`Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread`
` 0   ???         0000000000 0 + 0`
` 1   QtCoreVBox  0x0183b692 QIconvCodec::convertToUnicode(char const*, ...`  The solution accepted solves this issue too, in case somebody is having the same errors as I am.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a reasonable guess.

Can you compile a test case which crashes on Mac but succeeds on Linux or Windows?

Of course, you can look at the source code -- Qt function bodies tend to be quite small and highly-factored, so it should be easy to see what's wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on any of my other machines running OS X. This is my primary development machine so I'm frustrated that I can't run / debug any Qt applications (including the IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your addresses, I can see they are 64bit. Maybe you are having some type of incompatibility between 32 and 64bit binaries?

Comment: The linker and/or loader would choke, no?